# How to set up a vlookup or macro so that the values follow the date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where I want the values to follow the date. The dates are shifted with the macro and the dates have a vlookup set for the date. However, when my dates shift, the values don't follow the date, and I have something like this:

[image]

my code:

```
wbMe.Worksheets("input_6").Range("X26").Delete xlShiftToLeft
wbMe.Worksheets("input_6").Range("AJ26").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Range("AI26").Value)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by *"the values don't follow the date"* Please also show a screeshot of what you expect as correct result.

Comment: I would like to set a vlookup like this or another function, thanks to which the value under 2021-03 will always be connected with the date 2021-03 and not as in the example from 2020-12

Comment: It is completely unclear how your sheet looked before your code runs and how it looks after. Please see [mcve] and provide a proper example with example data and how it looks before and after running the code as well as what you ecpect as correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,CELL("col",D3)))` to point to the date row. Where `D3` is each VLOOKUP cells own address. So each cell would put its own address into that formula, and the formula returns the date of its own column.

This formula will create a reference that always points to row 2 of the cells current column.

A normal VLOOKUP Formula: `=VLOOKUP(P2,A1:F11,2,FALSE)`

Modified to use Indirect:  `=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,CELL("col",P3))),A1:F11,2,FALSE)`

Here is a breakdown of what that formula is doing:

`CELL("col",P3)` : Returns the column value of the given address (Column P = 16)

`ADDRESS(2,16)` :  Returns the address of a cell as a string, given the row & column values (Row 2 Column 16 => "$P$2")

`INDIRECT("$P$2")` : Takes an address as a string, and gives the value in the cell at that address.

Comment: so my vlookup looks =vlookup(X26;B1:AE13;2;0) so i need do like : =VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,CELL("col",x27)),x26:ae13,2,FALSE) What's mean col ? in there ?

Comment: Yes, so this formula would be going into cell X27 and would be using X2 as the VLookup value. if you wanted to use X26 as the vlookup value, you can change the `ADDRESS(2,` into `ADDRESS(26,`. The Col is the named argument in the CELL function, you can read about that one [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf). "Col" means that it is returning the cell's column number.

Comment: This one its not work i got #N/D! . =hlookup(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,cell("col",X26)));B1:AE13,2,false)